# NodeJS fs.readdir for network share or file: protocol

Tags: node.js, remote-access, fs

I am working on a project that requires reading directory content from a network share.

Is there a way to use fs.readdir() on a network share? I tried:

a) inputting in the share location directly

\\000.00.00.00\Example\Images

b) mounting the share as a drive and using the drive location

Z:\Images

In both cases, fs was unable to find the directory.

Alternatively, are they any modules that can read directory contents using the file: protocol? I tried: request, needle, and  SMB2 with no success.

Comment: I developed an application and I use "`fs.readdirSync`" to read the contents of disks.
If I run my application with "`node my_application.js`", readdir works perfectly even on network drives. But doesn't work if I run my app as a service.
And you...? How do you launch your application..? And did you find a solution...?